# Django | Al hacer un INSERT devuelve error: column "numberquestion" of relation "testapp_useranswers" does not exist

Tags: python, sql, django

Si la insert se hace con las siguientes dos variables a las dos columnas correspondientes, la insert funciona perfectamente:

**Funciona bien:**

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = '''INSERT INTO testapp_useranswers (user_id, modality_id) VALUES (%s,%s)'''
cursor.execute(query, [userAnswer, modalityPost])
```

**En cambio de la siguiente manera devuelve error:**

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = '''INSERT INTO testapp_useranswers (user_id, modality_id, numberQuestion, correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion, wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''
cursor.execute(query, [userAnswer, modalityPost, numberQuestion, ansOK, ansWrong])
```

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(de hecho si quito del insert numberQuestion, el que devuelve mismo error es correctAnswerCounterSameQuestionm y sino el siguiente wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Model:**

```
class UserAnswers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    modality = models.ForeignKey(Modality,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    numberQuestion = models.IntegerField('Número pregunta',null=True,blank=True)
    correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion=models.IntegerField('Veces que se ha respondido una pregunta correctamente',null=True,blank=True)
    wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion=models.IntegerField('Veces que se ha respondido una pregunta incorrectamente',null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.numberQuestion)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('test_app:test-hacertest', args=[self.user])
```

**Arquitectura tablas (PostgreSql):**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

View:

```
def saveUserAnswer(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        answerCorrectPost = request.POST['answer']
        modalityPost = request.POST['modality']
        numberQuestion = int(request.POST['numberQuestion'])
        selectedAnswer = request.POST['selectedAnswer']
        userAnswer= 1
        ansOK = 1
        ansWrong = 1
        print(answerCorrectPost)
        print(modalityPost)
        print(numberQuestion)
        print("Respuesta del usuario: "+ selectedAnswer)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = '''INSERT INTO testapp_useranswers (user_id, modality_id, numberQuestion, correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion, wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''
        cursor.execute(query, [userAnswer, modalityPost, numberQuestion, ansOK, ansWrong])
        print("Insert completo")
```

Template:

```
<form class="form-signin p-1" action="{% url 'test_app:saveUserAnswer' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for tes in object_list %}
  <div class="text-center mb-4">
    <h3 class="h4 mb-3 font-weight-normal text-secondary">{{ tes.nameModality }}</h3>
  </div>      
  <div class="text-left mb-4">
    <h3 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">{{ tes.number }}.-{{ tes.question }}</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox mb-3">
    <label class="ml-4">
      <input id="idCheckboxA" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="A" name="nameCheckboxA" /><a id="aidCheckboxA"> A .-{{ tes.a }}</a><br>
      <input id="idCheckboxB" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="B" name="nameCheckboxB" /><a id="aidCheckboxB"> B .-{{ tes.b }}</a><br>
      <input id="idCheckboxC" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="C" name="nameCheckboxC" /><a id="aidCheckboxC"> C .-{{ tes.c }}</a><br>
      <input id="idCheckboxD" type="checkbox" class="radio form-check-input" value="D" name="nameCheckboxD" /><a id="aidCheckboxD"> D .-{{ tes.d }}</a><br>
      <input id="Answer" style="visibility:hidden" type="hidden" name="answer" value="{{ tes.get_answer_display }}"><br>
      <input id="Modality" style="visibility:hidden" type="hidden" name="modality" value="{{ tes.nameModality.id }}"><br>
      <input id="NumberQuestion" style="visibility:hidden" type="hidden" name="numberQuestion" value="{{ tes.number }}"><br>
      <input id="SelectedAnswer" style="visibility:hidden" type="text" name="selectedAnswer" value="asdf">dsfgsdfg<br>

    </label>

{% endfor %}
  </div>
  
  <button id="nextButton" style="background-color:#250F64; color:white; display:none" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Siguiente</button>
  <a href="{% url 'home_app:home' %}"><p class="text-center mt-3">Volver a la página principal</p></a>

</form>
```

Comment: Parece que está todo correcto. Algunas personas he visto que para solucionarlo eliminan `migrations` y vuelven a generar todo (`migrate`, `makemigrations`).

Comment: Iba a hacer la misma sugerencia. Cuando yo he encontrado errores similares se debían a discrepancias entre el modelo de base de datos que estaba manejando mi rama del proyecto (git) y lo que realmente había en la base de datos.

Comment: Haré la prueba y os lo comentaré. Algo que he aprendido estos días que no me había dado cuenta es en el nombre de las columnas. Ya que en los modelos los definimos de una manera, en cambio PostgreSQL lo tiene de otra manera (es cini hay que llamarlos para hacer custom sql). Ejemplo en el modelo he definido como modality, en cambio PostgreSQL lo llama modality_id (claro que por ser una foreignkey etc). Un saludo y gracias una vez más.

Comment: Curioso, acabo de probado makemigrations y migrate, y sigue devolviendo: "column "numberquestion" of relation "testapp_useranswers" does not exist
LINE 1: ...T INTO testapp_useranswers (user_id, modality_id, numberQues..." Lo siguiente es borrar la base de datos y crearla de nuevo.

Comment: He probado borrar la base de datos, crearla de nuevo, migrar... pero devuelve el mismo error: column "numberquestion" of relation "testapp_useranswers" does not exist
LINE 1: ...T INTO testapp_useranswers (user_id, modality_id, numberQues...

Answer (score 1):

El error era las comillas que le faltaban a los nombres de las columnas:

**Debe ser así**

```
query = '''INSERT INTO testapp_useranswers (user_id, modality_id, "numberQuestion", "correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion", "wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion") VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''
```

**Y no debe ser así:**

```
query = '''INSERT INTO testapp_useranswers (user_id, modality_id, numberQuestion, correctAnswerCounterSameQuestion, wrongAnswerCounterSameQuestion) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''
```